# How do I test php code for twitter stream

Tags: php, twitter

I have the following function that is supposed to open up a twitter stream for me

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);

$query_data = array('track' => 'facebook');
$user = 'xxx';  // replace with your account
$pass = 'xxx';  // replace with your account

$fp = fsockopen("ssl://stream.twitter.com", 443, $errno, $errstr, 30);
if(!$fp){
    print "$errstr ($errno)\n";
} else {
    $request = "GET /1/statuses/filter.json?" . http_build_query($query_data) . " HTTP/1.1\r\n";
    $request .= "Host: stream.twitter.com\r\n";
    $request .= "Authorization: Basic " . base64_encode($user . ':' . $pass) . "\r\n\r\n";
    fwrite($fp, $request);
    while(!feof($fp)){
        $json = fgets($fp);
        $data = json_decode($json, true);
        if($data){
            //
            // Do something with the data!
            //
            echo $data . "<br />";
        }
    }
    fclose($fp);
}
?>
```

This is my first time ever to use php at all, so I'm completely oblivious as to what to do with this     $data    variable, this echo line does not produce any output on the browser. I'm sure this is trivial but a first-timer for me.

EDIT: The question is, what do I do with $data to make sure the code works? do I just shoot the file in a browser? it keeps saying "waiting for localhost..." forever

Comment: What do I do with the $data variable to check if the code actually works?

Comment: Try and test it on a live server. It sounds like there is a configuration issue with your testing server (localhost)

Comment: Now the browser keeps cycling displaying "waiting for localhost.." should I edit the question or start a new one?

Comment: In all honesty, I don't have access to a live server, sorry.

Comment: Well, what are you planning on doing with this once it's done??

Answer (score -1):

Why not just check to see if it's an array after the `json_decode`?

```
if( is_array( $data ) and count( $data ) ) // Ensures that json_decode created an array and has more than one element
{
    // do your processing, it should be okay
}
else
{
    // it's broken, error out
}
```

Comment: The response is probably going to be an object, not an array.

Comment: `This is my first time ever to use php at all,` He states it's his first time with PHP. Doubtful this will help him. :)

Comment: Fair, @ceejaoz, but he's returning an associative array already... `json_decode($json, true);`

Comment: This doesn't help either, stil cycles forever

Comment: @KamalSalem Where did you get this code? What is it expected to pull?

Comment: just a sample I found online, supposed to pull all tweets mentioning facebook in real-time